# Non-literal translation of "Muita luz para você"

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

I understand it means "lots of light for you" but I am hoping to get an origin and a better understanding of what this means? Is it religious? Is it slang?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Light` here usually stands for `wisdom`, `insight`, in a sense that has also existed in English since at least the 18th Century (think of the period known as "[Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment#Definition)"). Then, wishing "light" means wishing for the person to be "enlightened".

It can also stand for `hope`, as in "Ver uma luz no fim do túnel." ([light at the end of the tunnel](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel)), or, in general, a positive state of mind.

It's very often at least vaguely *spiritual*, or even religious, where "light" is usually associated with some God, often the Biblical one.

It can also mean `good fortune`, like in "Que Deus ilumine seu caminho" ("May God lighten your way."), where one's essentially wishing easier, lighter paths, i.e., `luck`.

Comment: @ANeves It's certainly the most common case, but by no means always. The positive thought movement, for instance, also uses the word in this 'hope/wisdom' sense, with no religious reference. See, e.g., [here](https://www.jrmcoaching.com.br/blog/sempre-ha-uma-luz-no-fim-do-tunel/).